# Would the same question but in the other language (English or Esperanto) be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Questions and answers in English won't benefit all Esperanto-speakers, and questions and answers in Esperanto won't benefit the new learners that are really at the commencing state.

Answer (score 5):

Please do not segregate your community by dividing it into two information entities. That is not how we scoped this site to work together as one community. It will only create a second-class experience.

The purpose of Stack Exchange is to curate the best possible answer to the question at hand by assuring the best possible *information* rises to the top. Disjointed efforts will only segregate the information into "our answer" and "their answer", depending on *which side of the isle* you post it. That is not how this site should work.

If making this information available in Esperanto and English is paramount, I suggest **working *together*** to make every awesome post available to *everyone* by translating the information *in place.* It doesn't make sense to split up your expertise (and the vetting/improvements that goes with it) based on whether it is asked in Esperanto or English.

Help each other out and make this *ONE* great site for everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I would be for not considering them as duplicate, for these reasons:

- The StackExchange will be useful for more people
- People tend to answer in the language of the question, so there is no repetition
- Even if we can edit the messages from others in order to add a translation, nobody does that

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are asking the same question, they are duplicates. It doesn't matter which language is used to ask the question.

Rather than having the same question asked in two different languages, it would be better to edit the question to add the translation in the other language, right after the original question.